# Setuptools with a dynamic shared library

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries, setuptools, pybind11

I try to make a very simple python package using setuptools for a project which contains a dynamic shared file, my folder is structured as follow :

```
project
 + setup.py
 + libmypackage
   + __init__.py (empty file)
   + libmypackage.so
```

the setup.py contains :

```
setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='1.0',
    packages=['libmypackage'],
    package_data={'libmypackage': ['libspylizard.so']},
    include_package_data = True,   
)
```

I'd like to use the package `mypackage` just with `import mypackage` with everything in `libmypackage` visibible at the root level.

1 - After `python setup install --user` the package `mypackage` is installed (`pip list`) but i can't import it.

2 - I can import `libmypackage` (that's not the name of the name...) but it contains nothing. I tried to write from `libmypackage import *` in the `__init__.py` but without any success..

I'll really appreciate help.

Best regards.